# How can I run multiple notifications on flutter with specified time for each one?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, dart-pub

I use a notifications that repeat every hour with different id and channel , but i got just the first one evert time and other blocked and sometimes lastone only.

this is my notification function

```
Future<void> _scheduleNotification(id,duration,channelname,channelid,soundandroid,soundios,message,title) async {

   var vibrationPattern = Int64List(4);
   vibrationPattern[0] = 0;
   vibrationPattern[1] = 1000;
   vibrationPattern[2] = 5000;
   vibrationPattern[3] = 2000;
 var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
       channelid,
       channelname,
       'your other channel description',
       icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
       importance: Importance.Max,
       priority: Priority.High,
       ongoing: true,
       autoCancel: false,
       sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(soundandroid),
       largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
       vibrationPattern: vibrationPattern,
       enableLights: true,
       color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
       ledColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
       ledOnMs: 1000,
       ledOffMs: 500);
   var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
       IOSNotificationDetails(sound:soundios);
   var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
       androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
   await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
       id,
       title,
       message,
       RepeatInterval.Hourly,
       platformChannelSpecifics,
       );
   }
```

and I call this function to be executed

```
 Future<void> smartnotificationcall(channelname,id)
 async{
   if(channelname=="clean"){ Duration(seconds:5); return _scheduleNotification(1,20,'clean',"clean","clean","clean.wav",'test','test');}
   if(channelname=="sport"){ Duration(seconds:20); return _scheduleNotification(2,30,"sport","sport","sport","sport.wav",'test','test');}
   if(channelname=="eat"){ Duration(seconds:40); return _scheduleNotification(3,30,"eat","eat","eat","eat.wav",'test','test');}
   if(channelname=="getout"){ Duration(seconds:50); return _scheduleNotification(4,30,"getout","getout","getout","getout.wav",'test','test');
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which platform do you use? Android uses [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) to schedule repeating notifications and they are inexact and this is documented Android behaviour.

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply , I use flutter , and this code are working for both ios and android , there is also in flutter alarm_manager , but it's working just in android.

Comment: I use the same notification plugin in flutter, if you want to receive exact notifications you should use .scheduleNotification and when first notification fires, schedule next one. There is no way to schedule exact repeating notifications for Android, for iOS it works fine

Comment: thanks again ,I think I have found a way to do that , using reapet Interval function , and I tried sheduled before and it s not working exactly as I want , I will test also the way you said to lanch sheduled from other sheduled I don't know exactly if it will execute the function code again if I call it or no , but if I use the same function inside it imagin what will happen it will generate a big number of sheduled that will stop machine s work